# PHP Variables - opposite strings

Tags: php, refactoring

I have a single variable $width that can be a string with any one of these values:

shortest, short, half, long, longest

In my template, I want to create 2 elements - one that has the original value of $width and one that has an opposite width:

- short is opposite of long and vice-versa
- shortest is opposite of longest and vice-versa
- half is opposite of half

This is my code which is working exactly as I want it, but it feels a little repetitive and dirty to me, so I was wondering if a cleaner/smarter PHP syntax exists to store the opposite string pairs and refactor/shorten the code or is that as lean as it can get?

```
<?
// Possible values - shortest, short, half, long, longest 
$width = '';

if ($width == 'shortest') {
    $opposite_width = 'longest';
}
if ($width == 'short') {
    $opposite_width = 'long';
}
if ($width == 'half') {
    $opposite_width = 'half';
}
if ($width == 'long') {
    $opposite_width = 'short';
}
if ($width == 'longest') {
    $opposite_width = 'shortest';
}

?>

<div class="<?= width ?>"></div>
<div class="<?= opposite_width ?>"></div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could be using arrays....

Comment: Traditionally for something like this you'd use a switch statement

Comment: You could simply use an array as a "map".

Comment: Wouldn't `double` be opposite of `half`?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ You should start your PHP blocks with `<?php ` instead of just `<? `, since short tags have been disabled as default since a few versions back. Except from `<?= ` of course, which is still enabled by default. It makes your code more portable.

Comment: User arrays, you could make the key as $width value, and the value as $opposite_width value. So your array would look like this : $array = ['shortest' => 'longest', 'short' => 'long', etc.]. EDIT: Sorry, just see xander answered your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here a small example of how to use an array as a map:

```
$widthMap = [
    'shortest' => 'longest',
    'short' => 'long',
    'half' => 'half',
    'long' => 'short',
    'longest' => 'shortest'
];

$width = 'short';
$widthOpposite = $widthMap[$width];
```

Should be pretty easy to use in your code.

This could be optimized further because you have both directions in one map, when you could also use `array_flip` for the other direction, but in this case it's simpler with just a few values.

Answer (score 5):

You can make array with opposite values, kind of map like normal -> opposite. Simple implementation:

```
function getOpposite($word) {
    $map = [
       'shortest' => 'longest',
       'short' => 'long',
       'half' => 'half'
    ];

    if(isset($map[$word])) {
        return $map[$word];        
    }

    //reverse finding
    $flippedMap = array_flip($map);

    if(isset($flippedMap[$word])) {
        return $flippedMap[$word];        
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now you can use function in your view:

```
<div class="<?= $width ?>"></div>
<div class="<?= getOpposite($width) ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the flipping approach, for now I probably won't need it with just a few values, but in the future if I need to add more it could be very useful.

Comment: 1+  for `if(isset($map[$word])) `

Answer (score 4):

[Here is one method without array mapping](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/29f01bc469d72f9a275bf95663f6d8cd9ab24412):

```
// Possible values - shortest, short, half, long, longest 

function opposite($width) {
    $widths = array('shortest', 'short', 'half', 'long', 'longest');
    $widthCount = count($widths) - 1;
    $position = array_search($width, $widths);
    $newPosition = $widthCount - $position;
    $oppositePosition = $widths[$newPosition];
    return $oppositePosition;
}

echo opposite('half'); // 'half'
```

Taking a count of the array I don't have to worry about making a map, which means I can add to the array without having to modify the function. This could be further modified by passing in both the needle and the haystack, which means the function can work with multiple datasets (of any size array) without modification.

```
function opposite($width, $oppositeOf) {
    $widthCount = count($oppositeOf) - 1;
    $position = array_search($width, $oppositeOf);
    $newPosition = $widthCount - $position;
    $oppositePosition = $oppositeOf[$newPosition];
    return $oppositePosition;
}

$widths = array('shortest', 'short', 'half', 'long', 'longest');
echo opposite('long', $widths); // 'short'

$sizes = array('skinnier', 'skinny', 'average', 'above average', 'hefty', 'heftier');
echo opposite('above average', $sizes); // 'average'
```

Comment: When you don't have to worry about an array map you can just use the function as is when you create and then test an array @senectus

Comment: `echo opposite('x', $widths);` prints `longest`

Comment: Easily fixed @B001 if you want to test if the value is `in_array()`

Comment: _if you want to test if the value..._ I am aware of that, just wanted to mention that the posted code doesn't validate